# Why my dockerize angular project doesn't open angular index.html instead of nginx default?

Tags: node.js, angular, docker, nginx

I dockerize a angular project name demo-docker and try to run it with the docker image that I build. But whenever I run the docker image in the container it take me to nginx welcome page instead of angular app page. Here is my docker build command

```
# Stage 1: Build Angular App
FROM node:20.10.0-alpine3.18 as builder

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

RUN npm run build --prod

# Stage 2: Serve Angular App with NGINX
FROM nginx:latest

# Remove default NGINX configuration
RUN rm -v /etc/nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

# Copy custom NGINX configuration
COPY nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

# Copy Angular app files from the builder stage
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/dist/demo-docker/ /usr/share/nginx/html

# Expose port 80
EXPOSE 80

# Start NGINX
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

the nginx.conf file is below

```
events {}

http {
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name localhost;  # Update with your domain or IP address

        root /path/to/your/angular/app;  # Update with the actual path to your Angular app

        index index.html;

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }

        error_page 404 /index.html;

        location = /favicon.ico {
            log_not_found off;
            access_log off;
        }

        location = /robots.txt {
            allow all;
            log_not_found off;
            access_log off;
        }

        location ~ /\. {
            deny all;
        }

        location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
            expires max;
            log_not_found off;
        }

        access_log off;
        error_log  /var/log/nginx/your-angular-app-error.log error;

        # Additional configurations can be added based on your specific requirements
    }
}
```

The page I got is below:
[image]

The page I want after running the docker container should be like below
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You copy your static app contents to the default nginx directory, but you set a different root in your nginx.conf. Set the root to the correct directory

In Dockerfile

```
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/dist/demo-docker/ /usr/share/nginx/html
```

But in nginx.conf

```
root /path/to/your/angular/app;  # Update with the actual path to your Angular app
```